# Apache and Open Files

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

I've tried editing `/etc/security/limits.conf` but Apache would need a PAM plugin for that to work, right?

```
nobody soft nofile 40960000
nobody hard nofile 102400000
phpuser soft nofile 40960000
phpuser hard nofile 102400000
httpd soft nofile 40960000
httpd hard nofile 102400000
nginx soft nofile 40960000
nginx hard nofile 102400000
* soft nofile 40960000
* hard nofile 102400000
```

I've tried setting

```
fs.file-max = 20970800
net.core.somaxconn = 1024000
kern.maxfilesperproc = 16638400
kern.maxfiles = 819200
```

in sysctl.conf but still no luck.

I also have in the `/etc/init.d/httpd` set with `ULIMIT_MAX_FILES="ulimit -n 16384"`

```
ulimit -n xxxxxx
```

That works but it is only temporary. Would installing nginx fix this issue or is there a way to make this work?

The error is:

```
[...] failed to open stream: Too many open files [...]
```

Comment: "httpd soft nofile 64000"
"httpd hard nofile 64000"   This in /etc/security/limists.conf did not work?

Comment: I tried that and added * along with other user names. Nothing.

Comment: What OS your apache is on?

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Comment: Lijux Centos 6.x

Comment: Your question, and the absurd numbers you're trying to set, suggest that you are confusing per-system file descriptor limits with per-process file descriptor limits. It makes no sense, and will not work, to try to set per-process limits to such absurdly high values.

Comment: Find the pid of your apache process, then paste the results of `cat /proc/<pid>/limits`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the default httpd and configuration shipped with CentOS, Apache starts as user root (so it can bind to port(s) 80/443.  Set them for root, log out and back in, then restart apache.